# How to cut off a pick noise a little bit using an equalizer?

Tags: bass-guitar, daw, logic-pro

Maybe this question has an answer already, but search bar didn't help much :(

So I have my bass guitar part (in MIDI) and I'm using **IK Multimedia MODO BASS** as my bass guitar emulator (synthesizer or whatever it's called). In preferences of MODO BASS play style is set to "Pick" (you can set in to "finger" or "slap" also). I like it, but it's quite noisy. What is the approximate frequency range on equalizer so I can make this noise a bit more quiet? Or do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: I'd have thought it would be simpler just to don a pair of cans, and flick the eq. sliders up and down until you found something  *you* liked.

Comment: @Tim  It lies somewhere from 2.8 kHz up to 3.8 kHz but maybe someone has a more accurate solution that turn the volume down for that range of frequencies.

Comment: A better solution might be to try one of the other MODO Bass sounds.

Comment: A better solution might be to try an actual _bass guitar_...

Comment: @leftaroundabout  I think that your solution is actually the best.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An equalizer works on the complete signal.  It's like using a camera filter in order to mask some unwanted detail in a scene you are photographing.  A pick noise is a sharp "click".  This has a wide distribution across frequencies.  Going at it with an equalizer will take energy from the click while making it muddier.

If you want to work with an equalizer, do it by ear: the result will always be a bad compromise so there is no go-to setting satisfactory for all purposes.

More effective would be overdriving your simulated amp: that actually limits the effect of the click.

But frankly: you are using a guitar emulator.  Go through its settings.  Something like amount of pick noise should be adjustable, or you should complain.

Comment: Only "detach noise" knob is doing something similar but not quite. Maybe cutting some mids (on bass guitar) will work fine.